# Interface of XBee module with ATMEGA 168

Tags: serial, atmega, communication, xbee, zigbee

I have configured 2 xbee series 1 modules such that one will receive serial data from any other module of same pan ID and the other will send data to the previous mentioned one.

Now when I use a terminal software (XCTU) to check data transmission its fine. 
I want to send data serially using a ATMEGA 168 using xbee as transmitter. And another xbee will receive the data and send it to an ATMEGA 2560 based platform. I do not have any platform for atmega 168 so I kinda built a burner (bootloader circuit). The bootloader works.
I have connected pin 3 (TXD of USART0) of atmega 168 with data in (pin 3) of xbee module. I have made necessary power connections as well (Vcc=3.3V & GND ). But the xbee does not seem to send anything. Is there something I am missing ? Please help, as you may already figured out I am a complete newbie.

PS : before reducing my reputation please let me know what I am doing wrong so I may rectify that.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void uart0_init(void)
{
 UCSR0B = 0x00; //disable while setting baud rate
 UCSR0A = 0x00;
 UCSR0C = 0x06;
 UBRR0L = 0x5F; //set baud rate lo
 UBRR0H = 0x00; //set baud rate hi
 UCSR0B = 0x98;
}

void init_devices()
{
 cli();              
 uart0_init();  
 sei();              
}


 int main(void)
{
 unsigned char data; 
 init_devices();
 data =1;  

 while(1)
 {
     data =0x21;
     UDR0 = data;
    _delay_ms(2000);
    data =0x55;
     UDR0 = data;
    _delay_ms(2000);


 }

}
}
```

This is the code I used.

Comment: perhaps post your code as well? you could be communicating at the wrong baud rate

Comment: @geometrikal thanks for replying. i have attached the code too.

Comment: It seems you are not calling `init_devices()` from your `main` routine, so the UART is not getting setup. I found this on the web which could be useful http://www2.ee.ic.ac.uk/t.clarke/projects/Resources/zigbee/AVR/AVR%20Serial%20Link%20Howto.pdf ... it has example code for a serial port. Also, have you thought about burning the Arduino boot loader and then using the Arduino IDE / libraries etc?

Comment: I am going to try & run the program in another device today. I have written similar programs before and they have worked on other platforms. Can there be any fault with voltage levels or hardware configurations?

Comment: XBee requires 3.3V and UART level signals. P.S. did you try adding `init_devices` into `main`?

Comment: I tried doing that but with same result. The program was not running in the 2560 platform either,so I looked into the Baud rate and changed it. After that it worked but the 168 interface is not working no matter what. Fir baudrate mismatch only dots are seen in XCTU but in this case nothing appears at the terminal software. So my guess is that there is something wrong with hardware setup.
@geometrikal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the programming. Unless the fuse settings are changed the microcontroller uses its default 8MHz oscillator with a pre-scaler of 8. So effectively you should have a 1 MHz system frequency instead of 12 MHz. So for 9600 baud you have to put:

```
UBRR0L = 0x06; //set baud rate lo
```

instead of

```
UBRR0L = 0x5F; //set baud rate lo
```

This should take care of the problem. Though I do not know how to configure the fuses or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

- `init_devices()` *must* be called from inside `main()` otherwise it won't be run
- `data = 0;` and `data = 1;` do not send out the characters '0' and '1' respectively. They send out NUL and SOH: see http://www.asciitable.com, and these characters will show as nothing in a terminal emulator. Instead, enclose the values in quotes, e.g.   `data = '0';`, to send the characters '0' and '1' respectively.
- Check the baud rate. With `UCSR0A = 0x00;` UBRR0 should be set to: `(F_CPU / 8 / baud - 1) / 2;` (source: Arduino serial library) where `F_CPU` is your CPU frequency in Hertz. With that in mind `005F` seems like a funny value. Check the MCU frequency and calculate accordingly.

Some suggestions:

- Funny characters on the serial output do suggest incorrect baud rate, however they do not *always* appear.
- Download the Arduino IDE and have a look at / borrow their serial code.

> So my guess is that there is something wrong with hardware setup

- Don't preempt your trouble shooting but deciding on what the problem is ahead of time, or you might miss the real issue. I still make this mistake! :)

Comment: Thanks again will check again following your suggestions !!

Comment: Nice, please let us know if it doesn't work. I have a very similar setup running but with atmega328p. Also, to check baud rate you could connect the atmega168 to a PC?

Comment: @Geometrical .Thanks for all your replies. I have revised the program as you said (please check above ) and it was a very silly mistake to make. But still I am getting no output. I have a 12MHz crystal oscillator and I have my xbees configured for 9600 Baud rate. Now from the link below
http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php?postbitrate=9600&clock_speed_table=1&postclock=12&bit_rate_table=1
I have checked that with UBRR = 77 (ie 4D in hex ) I can get 9600 Baud with a 11.98 MHz crystal. Will that be ok or the slight mismatch is enough to throw my connection haywire?

Comment: I think that is ok, I forget the UART timing tolerances but less than 1% should be fine. Try connecting the 168 UART directly to the 2560 UART ( tx to rx, rx to tx, gnd to gnd ), bypassing the XBee completely and just check that. Do you have an oscilloscope? You could check the tx output with that as well.

Comment: Will do that thanks. Tried to simulate with Proteus but failed there too. Will try with a real oscilloscope in the new year !!

Comment: @Geometrical
I have tried putting output from MC to an oscilloscope. We have observed some square shaped waveforms with peak to peak voltage almost equal to +Vcc but the signals are not continuous and not what it should be. Most of the time the value is just +Vcc without any variation.